# Can I make google assistant understand my entities and train it for the same or I need DialogFlow?

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I know that DialogFlow can be trained for particular entities. But I wanted an insight on whether or not Google Assistant can understand my entities?

I've tried to search on official site but could not get clear understanding on whether or not I need to go for dialogflow.

Comment: Are you planning to develop an app for Google Assistant?

Comment: Kind of. I am confused on whether I should go for action on google by google assistant or I should go for dialogflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actions on Google will allow you to extend Google Assistant by writing your own app (i.e. an Action). In your Action, you can tailor conversational experience between the Google Assistant and a user. To write an action you will need to have a natural language understanding mechanism, which is what Dialogflow provides.

You can learn more about Actions on Google development in the official [docs](https://developers.google.com/actions/extending-the-assistant). There are also official informational talks about Actions on Google and Dialogflow online, such as
["An introduction to developing Actions for the Google Assistant (Google I/O '18)"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vOnStV8wJS8)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you mean with your last sentence, there is no way to define entities for Google Assistant other than Dialogflow. Regarding your question, there is indeed no information on how entities are handled and how good one can reasonably expect the recognition to be. This is especially frustrating for the [automated expension feature](https://dialogflow.com/docs/entities#allow_automated_expansion), where it is basically a lottery which values will be picked up and which will not. Extensive testing is really the only thing one can do there.